# Modify filenames with patterns from another file

Tags: bash, filenames

I have these filenames :

```
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1033.bam 
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1044.bam 
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1045.bam
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1054.bam
```

I have this csv file :

```
16S_For_bc1005;16S_Rev_bc1033;Pa_32_S2_Rp
16S_For_bc1005;16S_Rev_bc1035;Pa_29_S2_Rp
16S_For_bc1005;16S_Rev_bc1044;Pa_15_S2_Rp
16S_For_bc1005;16S_Rev_bc1045;Pa_13_S2_Rp
16S_For_bc1005;16S_Rev_bc1054;Pa_25_S2_Rp
16S_For_bc1005;16S_Rev_bc1056;Pa_12_S2_Rp
```

I need to add the pattern (3rd column) of the csv file to the corresponding filenames, to get :

```
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1033.Pa_32_S2_Rp.bam 
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1044.Pa_15_S2_Rp.bam 
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1045.Pa_13_S2_Rp.bam
demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1054.Pa_25_S2_Rp.bam
```

The trick is to match the good pattern with the good filename : it is based on the 1st and 2nd column of the csv. It may happen some lines of the csv file do not match with any filename (`16S_For_bc1005;16S_Rev_bc1035;Pa_29_S2_Rp` for example, because there is not the filename `demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1035.bam`)

I try to deal with this topic first https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229858/renaming-files-using-list

Best

Comment: As for the syntax of your data: Can the csv file be syntactically **any valid** CSV (with semicolon as field separator), or does it always look like your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an awk that can print NUL chars, e.g. GNU awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r old new; do
    echo mv -- "$old" "$new"
done < <(
    printf '%s\n' demux.* |
    awk '
        BEGIN { FS=";" }
        NR==FNR {
            old = "demux." $1 "--" $2 ".bam"
            new = "demux." $1 "--" $2 "." $3 ".bam"
            map[old] = new
            next
        }
        $0 in map {
            printf "%s\n%s\0", $0, map[$0]
        }
    ' 'foo.csv' -
)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
mv -- demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1033.bam demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1033.Pa_32_S2_Rp.bam
mv -- demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1044.bam demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1044.Pa_15_S2_Rp.bam
mv -- demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1045.bam demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1045.Pa_13_S2_Rp.bam
mv -- demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1054.bam demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1054.Pa_25_S2_Rp.bam
```

Remove the `echo` when done testing. With any other awk, just print each file name on separate lines and modify the `while read` loop to `while IFS= read -r file; do` and do the `mv` on every second line read.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider using awk? E.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = ";"
}

FNR == NR {
    a[$1 "--" $2] = $3
    next
}

NR > FNR {
    name = $1
    sub(".bam", "", $1)
    sub("demux.", "", $1)
    if ($1 in a) {
        system("mv " name " demux." $1 "." a[$1] ".bam")
    }
}' filenames.csv <(ls demux*)
```

Or are you only looking for a bash solution?

Comment: I am looking for any solution which works. This one works, that's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding `ls demux*`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and consider using `printf '%s\n' demux*` instead., that call to `system()` will pass the file names to the shell unquoted (add `\047`s) and those `sub()`s will treat the `.`s as wildcards (escape them) so, probably mostly for the benefit of anyone reading this in future, there's a lot going on in that script that depends on the input files looking exactly like the ones the OP provided in their question. It'll also be very slow since it's spawning a new subshell for every file but maybe that's OK for the OPs needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[.;]' -v OFS=. '
    NR==FNR{
        a[$1"--"$2]=$3
        next 
    }
    ($2 in a){
        oldName=$0
        $NF=a[$2] OFS $NF
        print |"mv \47" oldName "\47 \47" $0 "\47"
    }
' filenames.csv <(find ./ -name "demux.*.bam" -printf "%P\n")
```

would do this

```
mv 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1033.bam' 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1033.Pa_32_S2_Rp.bam'
mv 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1044.bam' 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1044.Pa_15_S2_Rp.bam'
mv 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1045.bam' 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1045.Pa_13_S2_Rp.bam'
mv 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1054.bam' 'demux.16S_For_bc1005--16S_Rev_bc1054.Pa_25_S2_Rp.bam'
```